# Theoretical Panel Data Question - Take effects of a external variable

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, missing-data

Bellow, I have some samples of income levels for some countries. I am using these levels only to filter my data when running a Panel Data Analysis. 
I read a lot and could not find any info about how to use them, not as an X variable but without being my Y variable too. 
Let me try to explain better in a fake problem. I'm not sure if is possible or not.

If I want to test the impacts on the Human Development Index (HDI) of a country, based on its GDP and expected years of schooling (EYS). 
BUT
I'm running the regressions filtering the countries by its Income Level too. 
In my last test, I just used the 2018 Income Level, but I'm not sure if it's right to think this way, cause this level may change year by year. 

Example. If I use LM (lower Middle - 2018) for Angola, I am assuming it was LM over all the time and will place this country among all other LM. But, in 2015 it was in UP (Upper Middle) class.

Thinking on variable Income Level we get this:

When I run my panel like (just to read). `HDI ~  GDP + EYS`, it seems no problem. All here is ok because I'm not considering the Income Level.

The problem occurs if I run one regression for each Income Group, like `HDI ~  GDP + EYS, if Income == UM`. It will skip Angola 2005:2010 and 2016:2018, generating a lot of missing entries.

So, my question is: 
 
Is there any way to consider the variation on time over the income levels, without placing it as a variable on my panel analysis. Or the way I am doing it acceptable? (just skipping that country on some years with that missing entries)

```
    code country                2005 2006  2007 2008 2009 2010  2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018
1   AFG  Afghanistan            L    L     L    L    L    L     L    L    L     L   L    L    L     L
2   ALB  Albania                LM   LM    LM   LM   UM   UM    LM   UM   UM    UM  UM   UM   UM    UM
3   DZA  Algeria                LM   LM    LM   UM   UM   UM    UM   UM   UM    UM  UM   UM   UM    UM
4   ASM  American Samoa         UM   UM    UM   UM   UM   UM    UM   UM   UM    UM  UM   UM   UM    UM
5   AND  Andorra                H    H     H    H    H    H     H    H    H     H   H    H    H     H
6   AGO  Angola                 LM   LM    LM   LM   LM   LM    UM   UM   UM    UM  UM   LM   LM    LM
7   ATG  Antigua and Barbuda    H    H     H    H    UM   UM    UM   H    H     H   H    H    H     H
8   ARG  Argentina              UM   UM    UM   UM   UM   UM    UM   UM   UM    H   UM   UM   H     UM
```

Comment: It is very unclear - to me -  what "filtering" means in this context and also what exactly it you are hoping to achieve by "filtering" instead of simply controlling for income level by letting income level figure among independent variables.

Comment: I need to filter to show 1) the impact when looking to every country together. 
2) the impacts when looking only to High Income, Low Income, ...
I can't left Income as a variable because on my real problem I already have otherr variables that "capture" its effects. Working with about 15 variables

Comment: Or, how can I add the Income Level as a variable, without being as a dummie? As I'll work with over 140 countries, I probably will get a "fixed effect" for these. Or not?